# Try-catch isn't working properly

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

We have a problem in our staging environment. The try-catch blocks aren't working as expected, and we couldn't find why.

We are only running this test snippet:

```
try {
    throw new Exception('teste');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); exit;
}
```

Running that, we got an "Uncaught exception" error, and not the exception message.
We're not using namespaces.

Does anybody know what's going on?

We're using PHP 5.4.17, Apache 2.2.2, RHEL linux.

Comment: Is that snippet the only piece of code in the file you are running?

Comment: Is this code in a particular namespace? If so - use `\Exception` instead

Comment: Yes, that's our test script. We're not using namespaces. Already tried \Exception, didn't work :(

Comment: Sounds like something is failing somewhere up the stack. Can you get a stack printout? Are you using any PHP framework here? Cake, Codeignitor, Symfony?

Comment: We are using a framework, but in this test, we're not using anything, just a pure php file containing the script above.

Comment: @Denis Lins: what kind of help you're actually looking for then? SO is for programmers, not for fortune tellers. Show us some code that reproduces the error.

Comment: The code in the question's description IS the code that reproduces the error.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Ns3RK2 - no it **DOES NOT**

Comment: That's what I'm saying! hahaha... It's really strange, I'd never seen such a bug. In my machine, it works just fine as well. Just in the staging environment that the bug appears.

Comment: @Denis Lins: so - what kind of help you're looking for? We don't have a reproducible code. You're using *some* framework. How about contacting framework's author/support then? What if you create a file as in the example above and run it directly without **ANY** framework? Would it work fine?

Comment: I've found the answer. Thank all of you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

This is a bug in eAccelerator. I just disabled it, and the code magically worked just fine.

I saw it in this thread:
[PHP5: Why is try/catch failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692144/php5-why-is-try-catch-failing?rq=1)

I had googled it before, I just haven't found this thread.
Looks like upgrading the extension solves the problem as well.

Thank all of you that answered this question.